# Core data's managed object property as argument

Tags: swift, core-data, nspredicate

AnyThe first statement doesn't return any values, while second one works correctly. Is it possible to specify property name as one of the arguments to avoid hard coding?

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "%@ == %@", "id","553178666d61d70c24fe4221")

let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "id == %@", "553178666d61d70c24fe4221")
```

That's a complete solution thanks to @FreeNickname

```
  class func searchForObject(propertyName:NSString,property:NSString,className:String,single:Bool )->AnyObject?{
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: className)
        let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "%K == %@", argumentArray: [propertyName, property])
        var appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
        fetchRequest.predicate = predicate
          // Execute the fetch request, and cast the results to an array of LogItem objects
        var error:NSError?
        if let fetchResults = appDelegate.managedObjectContext!.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error: &error) as [AnyObject]? {
            if let e = error{
                println(e.debugDescription)

            }

            if single {
                var object: AnyObject? = fetchResults.first

                return object;
            }
            else{
                return fetchResults
            }
        }
    return nil;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `%K` instead of `%@` for the attribute name.
Like so:

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "%K == %@", "id","553178666d61d70c24fe4221")
```

Source: [Predicates Syntax (developer.apple.com)](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html)
From the docs:

> The format string supports printf-style format specifiers such as %x (see Formatting String Objects). Two important format specifiers are `%@` and `%K`.
>
> - `%@` is a var arg substitution for an object value—often a string, number, or date.
> - `%K` is a var arg substitution for a key path.